# How to : $\int_1^3 \sqrt{x^4+1}dx$

Tags: integration

> Calculate the integral :
>
> $$\int_1^3 \sqrt{x^4+1}dx$$

I need to solve this integral. I've tried to do a trigonometric substitution but it didn't work out for me, and also tried to use a integral calculator from the internet but it couldn't solve it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you suppose to approximate it using something like trapezoid rule?

Comment: it leads to an ellitptic function, this integral is not elementary

Comment: At best you’ll be able to come up with a numerical solution, either using a trapezoidal rule. I’m guessing your “integral calculator” wasn’t a very good one, any decent one would be able to evaluate this with relative ease.

Comment: i had to compare this integral with 1/3 and supposed that i need to solve it like a elementar integral, thank you for the help

Comment: @Tudor: it is immediate that $I\ge3$ !

Comment: $\sqrt{x^4+1} > x^2$ for all $x$.  So your integral is greater than $\int_1^3 x^2\; dx =  26/3$.

Comment: $$\int_{1}^{3}\sqrt{1+x^4}\,dx = \int_{1}^{3}x^2\,dx +\int_{1}^{3}\frac{dx}{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}} $$
is approximately equal to
$$ \frac{26}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{3}\frac{dx}{x^2}=9. $$

Answer (score 2):

This integral is not an elementary one (meaning it cannot be described as a solution in terms of standard mathematical functions), as its solution involves elliptic functions.

The result is :

$$\int_1^3 \sqrt{x^4+1}dx=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt2[-1 + 3\sqrt{41} + (1+i)F(i\sinh^{-1}(\sqrt[4]{-1})|-1) - (1+i)F(i\sinh^{-1}\sqrt[4]{-1})|-1)] \approx 8.98006$$

where $F(x|m)$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind with parameter $m=k^2$.

If that seems like **nonsense** to you, double check your calculations that lead to this integral.

If not, you'll want to use a numerical method to calculate this, like the trapezoid rule, as mentioned in the comments as well, which states :

> $$\int_a^bf(x)dx \approx(b-a)\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$$

Applying that, yields :

$$\int_1^3 \sqrt{x^4+1}dx \approx(3-1)\frac{f(1)+f(3)}{2}=f(1)+f(3)= \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3^4+1} \approx10.46$$

Note the difference between the $2$ calculations, that's a relative error right there. There are also more methods, that give you better approximation. You can check about these around the internet or in a book that studies ***Numerical Analysis*** .

**Update :**

Simpson's Rule (as mentioned in your comment) states that :

> $$\int_a^bf(x)dx \approx \frac{b-a}{6}\bigg[f(a) + 4f\bigg(\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg) + f(b)\bigg]$$

Can you use that and derive your result ?

Comment: yes, it worked perfectly using the trapezoid rule, since i had to compare it to 1/3.

Comment: I'm happy to have helped !